# big-o with division of exponents

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Sorry for poor formatting, I had a link for help which was deleted off a previous thread can someone please give me a new one? I was having issues trying to figure it out..

Anyway, I have having an issue figuring out big-o

This is HOMEWORK and I am not LOOKING FOR ANSWERS, maybe clarification if I have the correct answer but I need to understand 3 and 4 I am fairly certain I have one and two. Again I know HW is frowned upon, I just need help understanding...thank you

I am starting to understand, but there are some problems I cannot find help for.

Find the least integer $n$ such that $f(x)$ is $O(x^n))$ for each of the following functions:

(1) $2x^2 +x^8\log(x)$ I believe the dominant o here is $x^8\log(x)$ so I believe the answer is $9$

(2)$3x^6+(\log x)^4$ I believe the dominant o is $x^6$ so I believe the answer is $6$

This is where I get lost...

(3) $\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{x^4+1}$    Since the denominator and numerator are the same would the answer be 1?

(4) $\frac{x^3+5\log(x)}{x^4+1}$  I have no idea what to do for this one...

Comment: Before you do any of this you should really specify what the relevant limit is. From context it looks like it is $x \to +\infty$. With that in mind: #1: yep. #2: yep. #3: The whole thing is bounded so $n=0$ works. #4: Is the whole thing bounded (for $x$ far away from $0$) again? If so, could you even use a negative value of $n$?

Comment: Well, this is why I get confused lol the denom is greater than the numerator, so would we instead move to the 5log(x)?

Comment: Also the +1 is part of denom that is an error

Comment: Determine the dominant term in the numerator and the dominant term in the denominator (just as you did in #3). Typically if you divide by the ratio of these two, the resulting expression is bounded (and you can't divide by anything asymptotically smaller without making it unbounded).

Comment: but can a negative number be an o? these are the first 4 problems I have encountered in my studies so my knowledge is limited haha

Comment: It is possible that a function can be $O(1)$ or $O(\frac1x)$ as $x\to+\infty$. Note that $1 = x^0$ and $\frac1x = x^{-1}$. So technically the wording of the problem seems to allow $n=0$ or $n<0$.

Comment: There is no reason why not; big Oh notation is just saying that one function is bounded by a constant times another, when the arguments to each are close enough to some limit.

Comment: Ahh! ok I see! Thank you!